# Amazon S3 Object Lock and Apache Jclouds

Tags: amazon-s3, jclouds

I'm working on a project that manages multi-cloud storage using the Apache Jclouds library. I have just realized that Jclouds does not offer the Object lock concept of S3 and I am wondering how to do it knowing that I have made a lot of progress in the project.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Hello and welcome - I think your only way is to create an AWS S3 SDK client yourself and make the call via the client, as opposed to via jclouds.

Comment: Do you want to access with existing objects with object lock or create new ones?  The former should be supported by the portable interface but the provider interface lacks support for the latter.

Comment: The purpose of the application that I am developing is the archiving of documents. So I use a retention period during which the user cannot modify or delete the documents. Amazon S3 offers an object lock feature that helps protect documents even outside of my application.